# Possible to copy specific characters of a file based on a predefined condition?

Tags: java, properties

**Possible to copy specific characters  of a file based on a predefined condition?**

I have a method which copies a file, I need to add more functionality to this method so that characters before the = will solely be copied.

**Current Config File:**

```
runInTFS=true
browser=chrome
```

**My method will copy the file above to a new file (.properties) but nothing more:**

public static void copyConfigFileForTFS(String configPropertiesDirectory, String tfsConfigPropertiesDirectory) throws IOException {
    FileReader in = null;
    FileWriter out = null;

```
try {
    in = new FileReader(configPropertiesDirectory);
    out = new FileWriter(tfsConfigPropertiesDirectory);

    int c;
    while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
        char singleChararcter = (char) c;
        out.write(singleChararcter);
    }

} finally {
    if (in != null) {
        in.close();
    }
    if (out != null) {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

}

The method above will add a | after each character (For Testing purposes) i need a way to read :

Existing file (File which i will copy):

```
runInTFS=true
browser=chrome
url=example.com
```

New output File should look like (All characters after = need to be removed):

```
runInTFS
browser
url
```

I have the following method which will read and output the characters from the old file to the new file, I can append characters to singleChararcter and in turn will reflect the new file but how do I only read and write characters before the = on each line?

Comment: Since you're working with text files, perhaps it's time to learn how to use the `BufferedReader` class and its `readLine()` method?

Comment: @Kayaman thanks for your comment i have updated my original question with a method which reads characters from the .properties file

Comment: You know, when you read a line from the file, you can then modify that line. For example by removing a part of it.

Comment: Surely you know how to do string manipulation, if you know how to do File IO?

Comment: @Kayaman thanks again, currently I have appended a character to each line, just finding a way to create a new file and copy the next text to this file and then work the next step from there :]

Comment: It's pretty easy to do a loop of `readLine()`, `split()` (or other way of getting rid of the excess tail end) and `BufferedWriter.write()`.

Comment: @Kayaman thanks again i will give it a try now

Answer (score 0):

Because you are reading a properties files and you are looking just for the keys, you can also load the file content into an instance of a `java.util.Properties` and then loop over the keys.

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(youtInputFile);

prop.load(input); // load the properties file

OutputStreamos = new FileOutputStream("yourOutPutFile");
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));

for(Object key: prop.keySet()) {  // loop over the property keys
    bw.write(key.toString());
    bw.newLine();
}
```

This can give you the possibility to use Properties like `browser=chrome=aaa=bbb=ccc=ddd` without been concerned by the number of the position of the `=` sign